# Como passar parâmetros qry.filter Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

Preciso filtrar dados de uma grid, mas preciso passar por parâmetro. caso seja necessário voltar todos os dados. 
 Sempre faço da seguinte forma para mostrar todos os dados na Grid Exemplo:

```
SELECT FROM TABELA A
WHERE (A.NUM = :parâmetros) OR (:parâmetros = 0)
```

mas como posso fazer dessa forma no: 
`filter := 'num = :paramentro' or (:paramentro = 0)`

Comment: Que me lembre o "filter" tem de ser montado

    filter := 'num = 1234';

Você define que evento altera o "filter"

Comment: @Motta pois é, acabei usando com Like e quando quero voltar todos os dados para a grid passo um '%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma

```
 qryLista.Filter := 'UPPER(CSITUCTMNF)     LIKE'+ UpperCase(QuotedStr(situcacao))+
                     'AND UPPER(CTPDCCTMNF) LIKE'+ UpperCase(QuotedStr(documento))+
                     'AND UPPER(CTIPOCTMNF) LIKE'+ UpperCase(QuotedStr(tipo));
  qryLista.Filtered := True;
```

as variaveis situacao, documento e tipo inicio elas com '%', caso passo um outro valor a variavel fica da seguinte forma `variavel := '%'+ dados + '%';`.
Caso mudo o parametro para todos `variavel := '%'`